# $f \in C^{\infty}(A)$, $A$ compact then $f^{(k)} \in L_p$

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $f \in C^{\infty}(A)$, $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ compact. Is it true that $|| f^{(k)} ||_p < \infty$, for each naturals pair $p,k$?

My attempt.
Since $A$ is compact and $f \in C^{\infty}(A)$ then for each $k$ natural $f^{(k)}(A)$ is compact as well, and it is bounded specifically. So is it is $|f^{(k)}|$, and same as $|f^{(k)}|^p$, so for each pair $(k,p)$ the function $g(x;p,k) = |f^{(k)}(x)|^p$ is Reinmann integrable, and therefore is Lebesgue integrable. And the integral

$$I_{p,k} = \int_{A} g(x;p,k) dx$$

Since $I_{p,k} = ||f^{(k)}||_p$ this completes the proof.

Assuming is correct, can the argument be generalized for any measure $\mu$? If not where's my mistake?

(I'm a little bit rusty in these things).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f^{(k)}$ is bounded, i.e. $|f^k(x)|\leq M_k $, for any *finite measure* $\mu$ on $A$, i.e. with $\mu(A)<\infty$, you have
$$
\int|f^{(k)}(x)|^pd\mu\leq M^p_k\mu(A)<\infty,
$$
i.e. $f^{(k)}\in L^p(A,d\mu)$.

Comment: Can you specify what do you mean by "finite measure"? does it mean that $\mu(A) < \infty$?

Comment: @user8469759. Yes, I added that in the answer.

Comment: And the fact that $f^{(k)}$ is bounded is provided from what I said right? The fact that $f^{(k)}$ is Reinmann integrable is not usefull at all at this point. Because the boundness is a topological property while the integration depends on the measure, right?

Comment: @user8469759 Yes, you rightly said that $f^{(k)}$ is bounded as a continuous (actually $C^\infty$) function on a compact. Riemann integrability follows from continuity and boundedness. However, in the case of a measure $\mu$ it is relevant the integrability w.r.t. $\mu$. Or, since the function $f^{(k)}$ is bounded, simply the measurability w.r.t to $\mu$. So it is tacitly assumed that the measure $\mu$ admits all continuous functions as measurable functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your topological approach is good.

What you *hideously* use, is that a bounded function over a compact set has finite integral, which holds only for a certain type of measures.

It is quite clear that the condition on the measure is that it is finite on compact sets to have the same result. By taking the constant function $1$ you see that this is actually an iff condition.

Comment: So the specific case I've proved is correct, right? But I cannot use the same argument for a generic measure $\mu$, right?

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood what are you suggesting to prove the iff condition.